# Source of energy for artificial gravity in rotating torus

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, centripetal-force

I was hoping someone could clear up my (mis)understanding of the following:

Suppose we have a toroid-shaped spaceship that rotates around a central axis, which would create artificial gravity due to the centripetal force.

**My question is,**

1. once this spaceship is "spun up", would it continue to spin indefinitely?
2. And if so, would this mean that we're getting artificial gravity without expending any energy?

That doesn't seem quite right, since other forms of acceleration require lots of energy (huge amounts of mass in the case of actual gravity, or lots of 'mechanical' energy for acceleration from propulsion).

3. or will this spaceship eventually stop spinning and require continual boosting? (and why?)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the gravity of a planet *also* does not require the expenditure of energy: the Earth will continue to exert a force on you indefinitely, and it does not have to use up energy, or mass, to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will continue to spin indefinitely, just as planets do. Conservation of angular momentum guarantees that. The reason energy is not being expended, in classroom physics terms, is that no work is being done on the objects in the torus. The reason no work is being done is that work is the *dot product* of force with distance, which means the work done is zero if the only motion is perpendicular to the direction of the force. Since the force (and acceleration) is towards the middle, but the instantaneous motion is perpendicular to that, no work is done.

If the dot product doesn't mean anything to you, just know that work is force times the amount of motion in the direction of the force.

Answer (score 1):

Force and energy are two different things. Energy is conserved, a force is not. For example, magnets can apply a force on something forever and ever, not counting decay which is millions of years or zombie aliens. No energy required. All mass exerts gravitational force, no batteries necessary. Your torus, sure it requires spin up energy, but then, it will create a continuous centrifugal force forever, assuming no friction and you built it sturdy and again, no zombie aliens.